# Ошибка при установке twisted. fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: io.h

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-c++, pip, twisted

Python 3.5.3

Устанавливаю с помощью pip: pip install twisted

Проблема возникает с компилятором С++ в Visual Studio, командой cl.exe.

**Текст исключения:**

```
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src\twisted\test
E:\Games\VStudio\VC\bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32=1 -Ic:\python353\include -Ic:\python353\include /Tcsrc/twisted/test/raiser.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src/twisted/test/raiser.obj
raiser.c
c:\python353\include\pyconfig.h(68): fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: io.h: No such file or directory
error: command 'E:\\Games\\VStudio\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2



 ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python353\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\MYPABEi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-hcmi2wbn\\twisted\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\MYPABEi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-dgx2m4il-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\MYPABEi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-hcmi2wbn\twisted\
```

Ошибка: *fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: io.h: No such file or directory*

Я так понимаю, что компилятор не может найти нужные библиотеки? И непонятно где он их ожидает найти.

Тем не менее где они расположены я вкурсе.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как указать компилятору, где они находятся.

Comment: Связанный вопрос [What provides Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\io.h?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23297777/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решения непосредственно вашей проблемы в ответе нет, но есть обходной путь, чтобы по-быстрому установить нужную библиотеку. Этот обходной путь - [www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted) - на этом ресурсе регулярно появляются последние версии популярных библиотек - в виде уже скомпилированных для Windows колес ([wheel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel)).

Как установить:

1. Скачать колесо
2. `pip install <path>/lib.whl`

Comment: Точно. Видимо я оттуда в прошлый раз колесо брал. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ставите community версию vs с https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/downloads/

Заходите в visual studio installer, и для visual studio community в отдельных компонентах  ставите последние версии:

MSVS средства сборки C++

Windows 10 SDK - вот это ключевая штука, чтобы у вас io.h стал виден.

[image: скриншот]